# QLPreviewController works on iOS 6; not on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, qlpreviewcontroller

I've reviewed other posts regarding `QLPreviewController` not working under certain conditions. This one has me stymied:

`RHBlobCollection`and `RHBlobView` are model/view objects that respectively hold the collection of, and the individual displayable files, cached ahead of time.

RHBlobView.m:

```
    - (IBAction) handleBlobTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
    {
        QLPreviewController *previewController = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

        // view tag is index in array of blobs
        [previewController setCurrentPreviewItemIndex:self.tag];

        // blobContainer is type RHBlobCollection
        [previewController setDataSource:self.blobContainer];

        UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
        [navController pushViewController:previewController animated:YES];

    }
```

RHBlobCollection.m:

```
    - (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller
    {
        return [self.blobs count];
    }

    - (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller
                          previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
    {
        RHBlobView *blob = self.blobs[(NSUInteger) index];

        NSURL *fileURL = [RHCacheManager cachedFileURLForFilename:blob.filename withKey:blob.blobID];

        // URL proper?
        BOOL __unused proof1 = [fileURL isFileURL];

        // QLPreviewController can stomach it?
        BOOL __unused proof2 = [QLPreviewController canPreviewItem:fileURL];

        // Cached file actually exists?
        NSString *proof3path = [[fileURL resourceSpecifier] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];
        BOOL __unused proof3 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:proof3path];

        // Unless we're dealing with thumbnails, we're done. Return the URL of the resource.
        if ( ! [blob hasThumbnails] )
        {
            return fileURL;
        }

        // Process thumbnails into .pdf file for display...
```

`proof1`, `proof2` and `proof3` all return `YES`. Pulled out into a separate proof-of-concept project, `QLPreviewController` does as it's supposed to. In my full app project, though, it works under iOS 6 but hangs on "Loading..." with a spinner under iOS 7.

My gut tells me that it should have something to do with a malformed file URL or path, but my little tests show everything is copasetic. Has anyone else had a problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sake of completeness, I found the issue. I was actually using a subclass of `NSURL`, a simple affair that just added a separate string for the human-readable document title (`previewItemTitle`). When I changed things back to `NSURL`, things started working. Ugly titles for some weird filenames, but at least they appear. Back to the drawing board for how to handle that problem...

Answer (score 1):

I would agree
Under 6 previewItemAtIndex index is > 0
while with 7 index is Always -1  no matter the count 
Can you confirm ?

Comment: I got this issue when I was calculating the number of items incorrectly in numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController.

Comment: @NewDev, no, index is always the index of the document being requested. It is 0 for the first document, 1 for the second, etc.